# TypeScript Modal toggle

Tags: jquery, typescript

I need to display a Modal in TypeScript.
I used to do this:

```
$ ('# modal'). modal ('toggle');
```

in the js files
Now I want to simulate the same behavior by doing it on the ts file
How  can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install the typings for jquery, which you can get here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts

If you use typings, you can also simply install it this way:

```
npm install typings -g

typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

Next you have to import the module:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

Now the code should work for you:

```
$('#modal').modal('toggle');
```

I hope this was the base for your question?